# vue materialise autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, materialize

I am trying to figure out the Javascript I need to write to be able to get autocomplete to work on my page.

I am using Vue, Materialize.

```
<template>
    <div class="field center">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">textsms</i>
            <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
            <label for="autocomplete-input" class="font-size: 30">Ask</label>
    </div>
```

What should be the javacript code written to be able to search and display elements as someone types?

Cheers
Kris